# Need to display login user Name after successfull login

Tags: html, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS application and I would like to show user info in the header of the page when user is logged in. Something like "Welcome,{{username}}".

Answer (score 0):

> Your effort is Zeor.

We can not understand what problem you are facing but As I am also new in AnjularJs I can understand what you are asking for see the description below.

- You should create different routs for login and home, Let say `/login`  and `/home`.
- Then defile controller and template for both.

  ```
             when('/login',{
                  templateUrl: 'login.htm',
                  controller: 'loginController'
              }).when('/home', {
                  templateUrl: 'home.html',
                  controller: 'homeController'
              })
  ```
- Then in contoller check the authentication(best create a Auth service for check if user login or not) and redirect according result.
- In `homeController` request for login user data and show it in view some thing like this:

  ```
    mainApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
      function($scope, $http, $location) {
          var uAjax = $http.get("/getUser");
          uAjax.success(function(data) {
              if (data === 'failed')
              {$location.url('/login');}
              else{
                   $scope.userName = data.username;
              }
          });

  }]);
  ```

  home.html:

  ```
  <h1> Welcome {{userName}} </h1>
  ```

Me also new in angular, so if I am doing anything wrong please edit or comment.

Hope this will help you.